# The text of page is shifting/shaking somehow slightly in Android webview

Tags: android, webview

I used `WebView` to load a url in my app, the code was like the following:

```
webview = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);
WebSettings webSettings = webview.getSettings();
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            return false;
        }
});
webview .loadUrl("http://3g.qq.com");
```

The problem is the text on the webpage showing in the `webview` is always `shifting/shaking` to left or right slightly and regularly compared to its default position.

My device is `Android 4.1.1.` This issue disappears when i enable the hardware acceleration. But the issue also can be reproduced on 2.3.3 that doesn't support hardware acceleration.

Furthermore, `android 2.1` doesn't have this problem.

I searched a lot but without luck.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: post your xml file(where you've defined the webview). Maybe there's something in it.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

Add this line and try

```
webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
```

change like this

```
webview = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);
WebSettings webSettings = webview.getSettings();
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient()); 
webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        return false;
    }
});
webview .loadUrl("http://3g.qq.com");
```

Comment: It does not help. Thanks anyway.